# Creation RDS aurora cluster via cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a VPC with ec2 instances and 2 subnets and  2 availability zones through a cloudformation template,
I always get the same error when reaching the stage of creating  the RDS cluster /

```
Your subnet group doesn't have enough availability zones for a storage cluster. You must have at least two availability zones to map to a storage cluster.
```

you can find the templates in this link :
[link to templates](https://github.com/GaithMtiri/templates)

Comment: Can you provide the CloudFormation template for further analysis?

Comment: @jenswalter I added a link to the templates , the sunets and the Azs are created in the vpc file , and aurora cluster in db-cluster file , thnx

Comment: Your db-cluster.yml template works fine, I just instantiated one of those into eu-central-1. So there must be a mix up with the given parameters required for the template.

Comment: Can t it be a problem with the region ? Cuz I am.instancing them in north.virginia region

Comment: Any region with Aurora support should be fine. I created a gist on how I tested your setup: https://gist.github.com/JensWalter/6fabc564e530d46735192258dc786881

Comment: @jenswalter , I somehow manage to deploy the template you modified , still the original one doesn't seem to work , it 's the same probleme each time, it's always the same error , and I tryed to work in the same region as u did , nothing seems to work yet

Comment: Ok, then the issue seems not to be related to Aurora. Did you try opening up the Subnets to more address space, maybe you are running out of IP addresses? I think you can only start with a minimal stack (only the VPC) and add resources from that point onwards (like Aurora, ECS). That way you can narrow down the scope of the error source.

Comment: @jenswalter how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted AWS and they told me this is because Aurora is not available on us-east-1b and us-east-1f
There is no documentation about it and they are looking to add these AZs, but in the meantime you'll need to use another AZ

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this same issue and I was definitely using 2 subnets from 2 different AZs.  There might be some underlying backend issue... selecting different AZs worked for me.  ie - I was trying subnets from us-east-1a and us-east-1b, I switched to using subnets from us-east-1c and us-east-1d and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error which you have posted occurs when your `DBSubnetGroup` is confined to a single availability zone. I think both of your subnets are getting created in the same AZ.

In the [AWS::EC2::Subnet documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-subnet.html#w2ab2c19c10d375b9), it is recommended to leave the AZ allocation for subnet to AWS.

Removal of the Availability zone should resolve your issue.

Hope this helps.